# Can not get Kubectl context on Gitlab runner

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab

I had a problem with Gitlab Runner and Kubectl, I can get and set Kubectl context on my local machine
**kubectl config use ${context_name}
=> Switched to context ${context_name}.**

But when I created a Gitlab Shell executor and run switch context command like **kubectl config use ${context_name}**, I got the error **error: no context exists with the name: {context_name}**

I'm using Windows 10, any suggestion for this? Thanks

Comment: Please do not use images and put the content of the images as text. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, could you paste the text of the images into your answer? We ask that since it's easier for people to read things from the question itself. Thanks!

Comment: What output you have when you execute `kubectl config get-contexts`? Did you create context for gitlab runner? How did you configure Gitlab Runner?